# Entity Framework Navigation Property is null despite being explicitely included

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have two tables: `Fatture` and `FattureMail`
defined like this:

**Fatture**

```
    public partial class Fatture {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? IdentificativoSdi { get; set; }

    public string? ProgressivoInvio { get; set; }

    public int RegistroFattura { get; set; }

    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    public string NumeroFattura { get; set; } = null!;

    public string? RagioneSociale { get; set; }

    public string? Nome { get; set; }

    public string? Cognome { get; set; }

    public string? Provincia { get; set; }

    public string? Città { get; set; }

    public string? Cap { get; set; }

    public string? Indirizzo { get; set; }

    public string? Paese { get; set; }

    public string? PartitaIva { get; set; }

    public string? CodiceFiscale { get; set; }

    public string? IndirizzoPec { get; set; }

    public string? CodiceDestinatario { get; set; }

    public string? RagioneSocialeForn { get; set; }

    public string? NomeForn { get; set; }

    public string? CognomeForn { get; set; }

    public string? ProvinciaForn { get; set; }

    public string? CittàForn { get; set; }

    public string? Capforn { get; set; }

    public string? IndirizzoForn { get; set; }

    public string? PaeseForn { get; set; }

    public string? PartitaIvaforn { get; set; }

    public string? CodiceFiscaleForn { get; set; }

    public string? IndirizzoPecforn { get; set; }

    public string? ValMarcaDaBollo { get; set; }

    public bool ApplicaContributi { get; set; }

    public string? PercentualeRivalsaInps { get; set; }

    public string? PercentualeCassa { get; set; }

    public string? SpeseEsenti { get; set; }

    public string? SpeseNonEsenti { get; set; }

    public string? NoteCliente { get; set; }

    public string? NoteFattura { get; set; }

    public bool SentSdi { get; set; }

    public int IdtermPag { get; set; }

    public string? MetodoPagamento { get; set; }

    public string? Beneficiario { get; set; }

    public string? Iban { get; set; }

    public string? Banca { get; set; }

    public int? Stato { get; set; }

    public string RegimeFiscale { get; set; } = null!;

    public string TipoDocumento { get; set; } = null!;

    public string FormatoTrasmissione { get; set; } = null!;

    public string? NomeFileXml { get; set; }

    public string? Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FattureMail> FattureMails { get; set; } = new List<FattureMail>();
}
```

**FattureMail**

```
public partial class FattureMail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Idfatt { get; set; }

    public string Stato { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime? DataInvio { get; set; }

    public virtual Fatture IdfattNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

And I performed the following command:

`Scaffold-DbContext 'Server=****;Initial Catalog=Consulens;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=*****;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Model -Tables Fatture, FattureMail`

Now I'd simply like to retrieve a `Fatture` from a `FattureMail`:

```
    public static List<FattureMail> GetEmails(string stato = StatoFattura.INVIO_IN_CORSO)
    {
        try
        {

            return _context.FattureMails
                .Include(i => i.IdfattNavigation)
                .Where(x => x.Stato == stato)
                .ToList();

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            return new List<FattureMail>();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I explicitely included `IdfattNavigation` so why is it always null despite the referenced object exists (a `Fatture` entry exists whose `ID` is equal to the `IDFatt` property of `FattureMail`)?

I tried several asnwers provided on Stack Overflow but still nothing seems to work.

[image: Part 1]
[image: Part 2]

**OnModelCreating**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.UseCollation("SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Fatture>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_Fatturazione");

        entity.ToTable("Fatture");

        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
        entity.Property(e => e.Banca).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.Beneficiario).HasMaxLength(150);
        entity.Property(e => e.Cap)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .HasColumnName("CAP");
        entity.Property(e => e.Capforn)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .HasColumnName("CAPForn");
        entity.Property(e => e.Città).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.CittàForn).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.CodiceDestinatario).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.CodiceFiscale).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.CodiceFiscaleForn).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.Cognome).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.CognomeForn).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.Email)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .HasColumnName("email");
        entity.Property(e => e.FormatoTrasmissione).HasMaxLength(10);
        entity.Property(e => e.Iban).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.IdentificativoSdi)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .HasColumnName("IdentificativoSDI");
        entity.Property(e => e.IdtermPag).HasColumnName("IDTermPag");
        entity.Property(e => e.Indirizzo).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.IndirizzoForn).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.IndirizzoPec)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .HasColumnName("IndirizzoPEC");
        entity.Property(e => e.IndirizzoPecforn)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .HasColumnName("IndirizzoPECForn");
        entity.Property(e => e.MetodoPagamento).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.Nome).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.NomeFileXml).HasColumnName("NomeFileXML");
        entity.Property(e => e.NomeForn).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.NoteCliente).HasColumnType("text");
        entity.Property(e => e.NoteFattura).HasColumnType("text");
        entity.Property(e => e.NumeroFattura).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.Paese).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.PaeseForn).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.PartitaIva)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .HasColumnName("PartitaIVA");
        entity.Property(e => e.PartitaIvaforn)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .HasColumnName("PartitaIVAForn");
        entity.Property(e => e.PercentualeCassa).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.PercentualeRivalsaInps)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .HasColumnName("PercentualeRivalsaINPS");
        entity.Property(e => e.ProgressivoInvio).HasMaxLength(10);
        entity.Property(e => e.Provincia).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.ProvinciaForn).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.RagioneSociale).HasMaxLength(150);
        entity.Property(e => e.RagioneSocialeForn).HasMaxLength(150);
        entity.Property(e => e.RegimeFiscale).HasMaxLength(10);
        entity.Property(e => e.SentSdi).HasColumnName("sentSDI");
        entity.Property(e => e.SpeseEsenti).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.SpeseNonEsenti).HasMaxLength(50);
        entity.Property(e => e.TipoDocumento).HasMaxLength(10);
        entity.Property(e => e.ValMarcaDaBollo).HasMaxLength(50);
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<FattureMail>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("FattureMail");

        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
        entity.Property(e => e.Idfatt).HasColumnName("IDFatt");
        entity.Property(e => e.Stato).HasMaxLength(50);

        entity.HasOne(d => d.IdfattNavigation).WithMany(p => p.FattureMails)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Idfatt)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_FattureMail_Fatture");
    });

    OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
}

partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
```

Comment: Post the *entities*, not just the tables. ORMs like EF Map Objects to Relational tables - the important part are the Objects. Where does `IdfattNavigation` come from? This looks like an ID, not an entity. Scalar properties don't need `Include. If the entities match the table names the `FattureMail` class should have a `Fatture` property.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you or your input, I changed the question. IdfattNavigation is the navigation property generated by "Scaffold-DbContext" itself.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you again, but as you can see it's a "Fatture" property. Do you think there's a mistake in my Scaffold command?

Comment: Where do you tell EF that `IdfattNavigation` maps to the completely different `Fatture` table ? EF conventions are based on names and `IdfattNavigation` looks *nothing* like `Fatture`

Comment: If there's a mistake, it's breaking the naming conventions. If you have a Company with an Accounts property containing CompanyAccount objects, EF will automatically  map `CompanyAccount.Company`, `Company.Accounts`, ID, AccountID, CompanyID. If you break the conventions you need to explicitly specify objects and keys in `OnModelCreating`. The whole reason ORMs exist is to give the impression of working with *objects* like Company, Account and CompanyAccount, not tables or explicitly named navigation properties.

Comment: When EF Core don't return the expected result, first log the query and test directly in DB system.

Comment: Thank you but does anyone know how to resolve the issue? I let EF manage the work (database-first) so it's weird it mismanaged something. I am looking for several resources but nothing seems to work properly :/
For reference I am using .NET 7

Comment: What issue are we even talking about? You didn't post your `OnModelCreating` code, so we can't guess the properties and entities map to. The tables you posted earlier (and then deleted) don't match the classes. The images you added don't help at all, they just repeat what you already wrote.

Comment: Scaffolding the tables you posted earlier wouldn't generate properties with names like `IdfattNavigation`. It's clear the scaffolded code was modified but we can't guess how

Comment: Thank you for your very kind answer. I just added the OnModelCreating, whereas the images I added were for newcomers who might have preferred to have a quick look at the problem I am facing. The tables I added are the ones I applied the "Scaffold-DbContext" on, and never changed, why wouldn't they match? Everything was automatically created by EF.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos oh I understand, that's really weird then, because I did not edit it. I will investigate further. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Does the project use [custom scaffolding templates?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/templates?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nope, it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

For some reason, Lazy Loading is not active by default in newer .net versions, so we need to manually activate it:

- Install the following package: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies`
- Add the following line in your context's `OnConfiguring` method: `optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();`

Comment: Your question and code code ask about  *eager* loading, not lazy loading - that's the exact opposite. Besides, this isn't a new change, EF Core always worked like this. The behavior is clearly documented in [Lazy Loading of Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy). Enabling lazy loading doesn't affect `Include` at all

Comment: BTW that's why I kept asking about actual code that *actually* reproduces the problem. We can't know how the DbContext was configured. And, if lazy loading was the answer, the query you posted wasn't the one that returned nulls

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right, I was asking Eager Loading, not Lazy Loading, but honestly I am tired (it's a project at work) and if it works it works. Thank you for your answers and your help, but besides what I have posted I didn't know what else I should have. Have a nice day